# New to python and I need to write a variable to a file

Tags: python, linux, file

I need help writing to a file in python 2.6 .
I am new to python so i am a total newbie regarding this language.
I have the following code (part of the file) that I am trying to edit and I need to write the 'lin' table(?) to a file called keys.txt

```
    # create a list of input pressed button
    #----------------------------------------------        
    lin = []

    DeviceHandle = open(Configurations.PANEL_DEVICE)

    panelEvents = DeviceHandle.read(8)
    eventsLen = len(panelEvents)

    while eventsLen > 0:
      panelEventsStruct = struct.unpack('>II',panelEvents) 

      #print("EventType : " + "%i" % panelEventsStruct[0])
      #print("Event : " + "%i" % panelEventsStruct[1])

      EventType = panelEventsStruct[0]
      Event = panelEventsStruct[1]

      if EventType == PanelEvent.KEY_PRESS:
        lin.append(Event)

      panelEvents = DeviceHandle.read(8)
      eventsLen = len(panelEvents)

    DeviceHandle.close()

    inbut = len (lin)
```

---

I have tried putting the following code in the end but without luck

```
    f= open("keys.txt","w+")
    f.write(lin)
    f.close()
```

The code is running on linux on an embedded device!

Comment: Maybe you should learn the language at least a little bit before using it? You are expected to do some research before asking a question, as SO is neither a coding service nor a tutorial service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I know its not a coding service.
I just asked for advice because i can't find whats wrong.All the tutorials i read show that what i have done should have worked..
Anyway i will search deeper...
Thanks again.